# Opayo returning 5080

Tags: opayo

Has anyone called OPAYO via curl? I am getting a 5080 and I have no idea why

```
$postArray = [
            'VPSProtocol' => '4.00',
            'TxType' => 'Payment',                  
            'vendor' => 'rusticstone',
            'Crypt' => $Crypt   
            ];  
        $postBody = json_encode($postArray);
        $curl = curl_init();        
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            //CURLOPT_URL => "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp",
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postBody,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Authorization: Basic " . $auth,
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Content-Type: application/json"
             ),
        ));
```

I have just tried it using a form instead and it worked

$postBody is

```
{"VPSProtocol":"4.00","TxType":"Payment","vendor":"rusticstone","Crypt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
```

Thanks

Comment: I have removed "Authorization: Basic " . $auth,

Convinced that was the problem but it is still failing. Surely someone had got curL to call OPAYO for form integration?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you - not using a CURL request, but just posting an HTML form. In my case, using VPSProtocol 3.00 and posting to the live endpoint is the only combination that works. version 4.00 fails when I post to live, and both 3.00 and 4.00 fail when posting to the test endpoint. The `5080 : Form transaction registration failed.` error is very unhelpful!